# Accessing public method of another class

Tags: class

Basically, I'm trying to call a method in another class, but I'm running into errors.

Here is the **code**:

```
public class Ocean
{
    private static int gridWidth, gridHeight;
    private int safeCount;
    private boolean shipSafe;
    private static Ship[] ships;
    private static int[][] grids;

public Ocean(int a, int b, int c)
{
    grids = new int[a][b];
    ships = new Ship[c];
    for(int i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        ships[i] = Ship();
    }
    gridWidth = a;
    gridHeight = b;
}
```

I cannot access the public Ship class, and the error appears in `ships[i] = Ship();`
I've tried redefining it, adding a constructor.

Comment: Please format the code, and add a language tag (maybe Java?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the line ships[i] = new Ship();